setInterval() function not working JavaScript
I am designing a basic digital clock.
But the code doesn't seem to work.
I am attaching my code:
My clock.js file:
setInterval( function() {
    var currentTime= new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); // gets time from local computer
    
    var hours= currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes= currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds= currentTime.getSeconds();
    var period= "AM";

    if(hours >=12){
        period="PM";
    }
    if(hours >= 13){
        hours= hours-12;
    }
    if(minutes <=9){
        minutes = "0" + minutes; // so, 9:6 --> 9:06
    }
    if(seconods <=9){
        seconds= "0" + seconds; 
    }

    var clockTime= hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + period;

    var clockElement = document.getElementById("clock");
    clockElement.innerHTML = clockTime; 
}, 1000); // every 1000 milli seconds, the function will run



Here is my clock.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Digital Clock using JavaScript" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
        <title>Digital Clock</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner"><span>Your local time</span></div>
        <div id="clock">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


The setInterval() function doesn't seem to work.
Or, is there any error elsewhere?

"Or is there any error elsewhere?" - yes there is. Open the console to see the exception your code is throwing!

@Bergi thanks for the reply. I checked the console, and this is written there: TypeError: currentTime.getHours is not a function. (In 'currentTime.getHours()', 'currentTime.getHours' is undefined)

In this line:
var currentTime= new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

You're setting currentTime to a string, not a Date object, so when you're asking for currentTime.getHours() the method doesn't exists.
Change the line to
var currentTime= new Date();

Also, correct the typo in this line
if(seconods <=9){

Demo:


setInterval( function() {
    var currentTime= new Date(); // gets time from local computer
    
    var hours= currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes= currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds= currentTime.getSeconds();
    var period= "AM";

    if(hours >=12){
        period="PM";
    }
    if(hours >= 13){
        hours= hours-12;
    }
    if(minutes <=9){
        minutes = "0" + minutes; // so, 9:6 --> 9:06
    }
    if(seconds <=9){
        seconds= "0" + seconds; 
    }

    var clockTime= hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + period;

    var clockElement = document.getElementById("clock");
    clockElement.innerHTML = clockTime; 
}, 1000); // every 1000 milli seconds, the function will run
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Digital Clock using JavaScript" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
        <title>Digital Clock</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner"><span>Your local time</span></div>
        <div id="clock">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>




I would suggest you to dont set the date as "toLocaleTimeString()"


var currentTime= new Date().toLocaleTimeString();



Just do this instead:


var currentTime = new Date(); 



So you only need to return the new object Date(), you can use method "toLocaleTimeString" when you show/print the time.

The problem is solved, but I'll provide this just for fun (and some practice for me).
Run the snippet in full page and click the buttons.


function clockWidget ( clockConfiguration )
{
  const theConfiguration =
  {
    // Default options.
    
    // The id of the button.
    id: 'clockWidget' + clockWidget.generatorCounter,
    
    // The id of the display.
    idd: 'clockDisplay' + clockWidget.generatorCounter++,
    
    // The type of clock.
    type: '12h', // Any other value is assumed as '24h'.
    
    // The class of the button.
    class: 'clockWidget',
    
    // The click event of the button.
    click: clickEvent => console.log(clockButton.textContent),
    
    // The label of the clock.
    label: 'Your current time:',
    
    // The numeric value of how much the time should be shifted from updater().
    shift: 0,
    
    // The function that returns the updated time. Can be customized.
    updater: Date.now,
    
    // The given configuration only (usually a dataset).
    dataset: Object(clockConfiguration),
    
    // The interval to run the updater().
    interval: 1000,
    
    // The sate of the button.
    disabled: false,
    
    // Given configuration replace the defaults.
    ...Object(clockConfiguration)
  };
  
  const clockButton = document.createElement('button');
  {
    theConfiguration.clockButton = clockButton;
    
    clockButton.id = theConfiguration.id;
    clockButton.disabled = theConfiguration.disabled;
    clockButton.classList.add(theConfiguration.class);
    
    // Install the click event on the button.
    clockButton.addEventListener('click', theConfiguration.click);
  }
  
  const clockLabel = document.createElement('label');
  {
    theConfiguration.clockLabel = clockLabel;
    
    clockLabel.for = theConfiguration.idd;
    clockLabel.textContent = theConfiguration.label + ' ';
    
    // Install the label in the button.
    clockButton.appendChild(clockLabel);
  }
  
  const clockDisplay = document.createElement('code');
  {
    theConfiguration.clockDisplay = clockDisplay;
    
    clockDisplay.id = theConfiguration.idd;
    clockDisplay.textContent = '';
    
    clockUpdate(theConfiguration);
    setInterval(() => clockUpdate(theConfiguration), theConfiguration.interval);
    
    // Install the display in the button.
    clockButton.appendChild(clockDisplay);
  }
  
  clockButton.clockConfiguration = theConfiguration;
  
  return clockButton;
}

function clockUpdate ( theConfiguration )
{
  const theDate = new Date(theConfiguration.updater() + Number.parseInt(theConfiguration.shift));
  const lt10 = theDate.getHours() < 10;
  const gt12 = theDate.getHours() > 12;
  const is12 = theConfiguration.type == '12h';
  const parsedDate =
  (
    [
      ((theDate.getHours() < 10) ? '0' : '') + (theDate.getHours() + ( (theDate.getHours() > 12) && (theConfiguration.type == '12h') ? -12 : 0 )),
      (theDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + theDate.getMinutes().toString(),
      (theDate.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '') + theDate.getSeconds().toString(),
    ].join(':')
    
    + ( (theConfiguration.type == '12h') ? ' ' + ( (theDate.getHours() > 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM' ) : '' )
  );
  
  theConfiguration.clockDisplay.textContent = parsedDate;
}

clockWidget.generatorCounter = 0;

clockWidget.install = () =>
{
  const allClocks = document.querySelectorAll('.clockWidgetContainer');
  
  for ( const clockContainer of allClocks )
  {
    const clockData = clockContainer.dataset;
    const newClock = clockWidget(clockData);
    
    clockContainer.replaceChildren(newClock);
    
    clockContainer.clockConfiguration = newClock.clockConfiguration;
    
    console.log('New installed clock:', newClock.id);
  }
}

document.addEventListener
(
  'readystatechange', readyEvent =>
  {
    if ( document.readyState == 'interactive' )
    {
      // Install all clocks.
      clockWidget.install();

      // HARDCODED INJECTION CLOCK:
      const newClock = clockWidget({type: '24h'});
      {
        document.body.appendChild(newClock);
        console.log('New hardoded injected clock:', newClock.id);
        console.log('Last clock configuration:', newClock.clockConfiguration);
      }
    }
  }
);
.clockWidget
{
  background-color: #333;
}
.clockWidget code
{
  color: lime;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.clockWidget label
{
  color: lightgray;
}
<p>The clocks are buttons with <code>onClick</code> events.</p>
<hr/>
<div class='clockWidgetContainer' data-label="Current Clock"></div>
<div class='clockWidgetContainer' data-label="+3h Clock" data-shift="+10800000"></div>
<div class='clockWidgetContainer' data-label="-3h Clock" data-shift="-10800000"></div>
<hr/>
<p>Javascript harcoded injection clock:</p>



Indeed. The experience was pretty good. I'm accepting comments.
